# Can we Download Multiple Files and/or folder in c#

Tags: c#, windows, directory

I am having a Windows application where I want to download multiple files at a glance from the server.Will it be possible? Also I want to download the complete folder having subfolders or files. I am using c# as the programming language. Guide me for the same.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you stuck with?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Download via what? HTTP? FTP? You need to give more info and you should show what you've tried so far. :)

Comment: Are the files accessible using HTTP? Is folder listing allowed for that folder?

Comment: You cannot pull multiple files from the same http response unless your server zip's them up or something.

Comment: Right now my application is having a folder wherein there are multiple files in it and I want to download a folder or multiple files depending on the user selection so hows it possible?M not having any ftp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check DownloadFile method from WebClient.

Comment: do you have any link which describes the above method?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx checkit out

Answer (score 0):

In this case [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is you're friend .

You can create many WebClient object and use [`WebClient.DownloadFile();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) Method tu use
or you can use [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) than to create Directory's you can use [`Directory.CreateDirectory();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)